# why filter blur dose not show on android phone? action script

Tags: android, actionscript-3

Currently in an Android application that I'm have develop a android application that used filter blur. the filter blur work on android emulator(SDK) but when i publish it on real android phone and run it, the filter blur dose not work in run time. any idea what i missing here?

sorry for bad grammar...

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe that filters work when the `renderMode` is set to `GPU`. For filters to work, make sure it is set to `CPU`, although there may be some other performance ramifications of doing that.